# Como crear id de componente en vue 3

Tags: vue3, nuxt

Quiero conseguir que mi componente tenga un id unico.

Lo que hacia antes con vue 2

```
//vue 2
let uuid = 0;
export default{
 data(){
   return{
     uuid
   }
 },
  created(){
     uuid++;
  }
}
```

quiero saber si vue 3 tiene una alternativa para conseguir el id del componente. porque no consigo nada en la documentacion. agradezco si pueden ayudarme.

```
//vue 3
    <script setup>
    let uuid = ?
    
    
    </script>
```

Comment: Tiene que ser numérico? Podrías usar UUIDv4 y generar ids únicos

Comment: ¿Pdrías agregar un código donde muestres como usabas ese componente?

Answer (score 0):

Existe una opción nativa que no es recomendada, pero funciona.

Podés leer acerca de la misma acá: https://v3.cn.vuejs.org/api/composition-api.html#getcurrentinstance

```
import { getCurrentInstance } from 'vue'

setup() {
    const uid = getCurrentInstance().uid

    return {
      uid
    };
 }
```